# Would using positive numbered glasses while using a computer help prevent myopia?

Tags: human-biology, vision, eyes, human-eye, optics

There are multiple web pages linking screen-time and myopia. While this is not necessarily proven, for example as shown on the NIH page here https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31943280/ , it seems logical that exerting our eyes to look closer than "infinity" for long hours might cause that (myopia).

So I was thinking, what if we use reading glasses, glasses with positive prescriptions, while using computers, effectively changing the screen distance to be our "infinity" distance. Would that help alleviate the strain on our eyes and therefore myopia, or its worsening?